# On click on Tab bar item view is not changing in iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uitabbar

I want to use a Tab bar in one of the view for my application which is VIEW BASED APPLICATION. so i dragged a tab bar and added 2 more  tab bar Items to make it totally 4.

I have Tagged each Tab Item with 1,2,3,4 with Myservices,History,RecentRequest and profile label respectively.

similarly i have added 4 Classes for each tab with name  Myservices.h,.m,.xib name and same names as above for other tabs as well.

In this above Tabs 3 are subclass of UITableViewController and profile tab is subclass of UIVIewController. when i click on profile tab its showing tableView and i have done some modification in other views as well but on click  on any TAB its showing same screen for the the all Tabs so can anyone tel me where i am going wrong.

This is my code I have added this code in class called Homepage.h and .m and tab bar is dragged in homepage.xib

//CODE
homepage.h

```
IBOutlet UITabBar *myTabBar; 
UIViewController *myServicesViewController;
UIViewController *historyViewController;
UIViewController *recentRequestViewController;
UIViewController *profileViewController;
UIViewController *currentViewController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBar *myTabBar; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *myServicesViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *historyViewController;
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIViewController *currentViewController;
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIViewController *profileViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *recentRequestViewControll
```

//HomePage.m

```
-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {

    NSLog(@"didSelectItem: %d", item.tag);
  [self activateTab:item.tag];

}

-(void)activateTab:(int)index

{

 switch (index) {
 case 1:
        if (myServicesViewController == nil) {

            self.myServicesViewController=

            [[MyServices alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        }

        [self.view insertSubview:myServicesViewController.view belowSubview:myTabBar];
        if (currentViewController != nil)
            [currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        currentViewController = myServicesViewController;           
        break;
    case 2:
        if (historyViewController == nil) {
            self.historyViewController =
            [[History alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        }
        [self.view insertSubview:historyViewController.view belowSubview:myTabBar];
        if (currentViewController != nil)
            [currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        currentViewController = historyViewController;          
        break;
    case 3:
        if (recentRequestViewController == nil) {
            self.recentRequestViewController =
            [[RecentRequest alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        }
        [self.view insertSubview:recentRequestViewController.view belowSubview:myTabBar];
        if (currentViewController != nil)
            [currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        currentViewController = recentRequestViewController;            
        break;
    case 4:
        if (profileViewController == nil) {
            self.profileViewController =
            [[Profile alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        }
        [self.view insertSubview:profileViewController.view belowSubview:myTabBar];
        if (currentViewController != nil)
            [currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        currentViewController = profileViewController;          
        break;
    default:
        break;
   }
}


-(void)viewDidLoad

{

UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"bg.jpg"]];
self.view.backgroundColor = background;
[myTabBar setSelectedItem:[myTabBar.items objectAtIndex:0]];
[self activateTab:1];
[super viewDidLoad];

}
```

Click on any tab the view is not changing can anyone tell me where I am going wrong??

Comment: i had missed one line of code that is [self activateTab:item.tag]; in the (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item  method. i have edited my code and it works fine...

Comment: Can u plz tell me where u set tags for each tab wheather it is in viewwillappear ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through code again and again i found out that i have missed one line of code that is `[self activateTab:item.tag];`

in the

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item method. 
{
    [self activateTab:item.tag];
}
```

i have edited my code and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Because of 
`[self activateTab:1];`

You select Tab index 1 thats why every time you get same tab you need to pass selected tab index every time rather then fix.

i also can not foud any selection of tab bar method for get a selecting tab bar index.

Comment: ya i tried if i change tab Index 4 it shows only profile page view.SO what i should change in the above code??

Comment: I have edited my above code.i have added this method as well in the above code - (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    NSLog(@"didSelectItem: %d", item.tag);
} But i am not getting what to add to select particular view

Comment: Please see this tutorial http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/tabbar-application-in-iphone/

Comment: for that you need to set tag of tab bar. select tabbar and set tag property of every tab. like 1,2,3 whatever.

Comment: you also connect it with interface builder?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/tabbar-application-in-iphone/

Comment: above link is Tab bar application i am using above code in view based application. u r giving link of tab bar application which is no link with above code

Answer (score 0):

Following code is use for creating the tabbar and it's view also we can change the view dynamically useing code for that following code is use.

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[viewcontroller1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewcontroller1" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[viewcontroller2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewcontroller2" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController3 = [[viewcontroller3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewcontroller3" bundle:nil];


 UIViewController *viewController4 = [[viewcontroller3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewcontroller4" bundle:nil];


    UIViewController *viewController5 = [[Deliveryviewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewcontroller5" bundle:nil];



            delegate.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, viewController3, viewController4, viewController5, nil];

            delegate.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;

            delegate.tabBarController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
            [self presentModalViewController:delegate.tabBarController animated:YES];
```

Into delegate maethod following things to do

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;
```

and synthesize of that UITabbarController

```
@synthesize tabBarController = _tabBarController;
```